# Accessing MySQL database server from Workbench on remote workstation

Tags: mysql

I installed a MySQL database server on Centos 7 on a machine with local IP address 192.168.1.40. I run all the post installation checks to make sure that the database is up and running. (It is)

I then installed MySQL Workbench on a second Windows machine (ip address 192.168.1.3) on the same local network.
It is my understanding that remote connection to a mysql database are disabled so I run on the database the command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.3' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

then I added to the /etc/my.cnf the string

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

and restarted the server

Trying to connect from the remote workbench to the server i get the error
[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: This looks like a connectivity problem rather than a permissions problem (though the latter may exist).

Comment: In this case mysql workbench provides a healthy list of tips to check. Have you tried checking those?

Comment: Yes, the port hasn't been touched (so I suppose it's correct) that address is pingable and correct, I double checked the password inserted. I don't know what else to check.